# sorting by first character

Tags: java

The question at hand is each policy No. is a string of 9 characters of which indicates the type of insurance policy

- B for building policy
- C for Contents Policy
- L for Life policy
- V for car policy

Each of the remaining 8 characters of the policy number is a decimal digit.

**I have tried using charAt but somebody told me there was a slightly better way**

```
public String getpolicyNo(String initpolicyNo) {

    /**
     * Access method to find the first character of the policy to then
     * determine what type of policy it is.
     */
    String b = "B";
    String C = "C";
    String L = "L";
    String V = "V";

    char c1 = b.charAt(0);
    char c2 = C.charAt(0);
    char c3 = L.charAt(0);
    char c4 = V.charAt(0);


    if (c1 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Its building" + c1);
        return initpolicyNo;
    } else {
        if (c2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Its Content");
            return initpolicyNo;
        } else {
            if (c3 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Its life");
                return initpolicyNo;
            } else {
                if (c4 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Its car");

                    return initpolicyNo;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

I'm not looking for you to provide an answer for me, I'm just looking for any possible alternatives and possible suggestions.

Many thanks

Dan

Comment: You can use a `switch` instead. Rest is fine.

Comment: And since c1-4 are characters how are you comparing it to 0?

Comment: Dont you want to compare initpolicyNo.chartAt(0)?

Comment: And you are simply returning the policy number you took as an argument (`initpolicyNo`) after you print. This is going to print them all. I believe you've got your solution wrong mate.

Comment: What is the question about `sorting` here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve, but I would write this way:

```
public String getpolicyNo(String initpolicyNo) {
    switch(initPolicyNo.charAt(0))
    {
       case 'B':
          System.out.println("Its building B");
          return initpolicyNo;
       case 'C':
          System.out.println("Its building C");
          return initpolicyNo;
       case 'L':
          System.out.println("Its building L");
          return initpolicyNo;
       case 'V':
          System.out.println("Its building V");
          return initpolicyNo;
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you using an `Enum`. Each value for an Enum has an ordinal value, which you can sort by.
If you want to read an introduction to Enums, the following site will help: [Enum Types - The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

```
enum Policy {
     BUILDING_POLICY, CONTENTS_POLICY, LIFE_POLICY, CAR_POLICY
}
```

For each enum value, you can assign a custom value, with which you can sort.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void whatItIs(String s){

  if(s.length() < 1){
    //-- nothing to see here ---
    return;
  }

  //-- case insensitive --
  char c = Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0));

  switch(c){
    case 'B':
      //-- its a building !--
      break;
    case 'C':
      //-- its a c........ !--
      break;
    case 'L':
      //-- its a l........ !--
      break;
    case 'V':
      //-- its a v........ !--
      break;
    default:
      //-- its something else :(--
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried using charAt but somebody told me there was a slightly
>   better way

there is no better way to get the first letter of a string than using charAt.

And rather than having lots of if's/switches and what not, get a bit more OOPs up side your head.

```
Map<Character, String> myMap = new HashMap<Character, String>() {{
        put('B', "Its building");
        put('C', "Its content");
        put('L', "its life");
        put('V', "its vehicle");
    }} ;
    public void iShouldBeDoingMyOwnWork(String initpolicyNo) {
        System.out.println(myMap.get(initpolicyNo.charAt(0)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getpolicyNo(String initpolicyNo) {

        switch (initpolicyNo.charAt(0)) {
        case 'B':
            System.out.println("Its building" );
            break;
        case 'C':
            System.out.println("Its Content");
            break;
        case 'L':
            System.out.println("Its life");
            break;
        case 'V':
            System.out.println("Its car");
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            break;
        }
        return initpolicyNo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add `enums` to your code, or you could use a `switch` statement instead of the `if/else` block you currently have:

```
    char type = initpolicyNo.charAt(0);
    switch (type) {
        case 'B':
            // do stuff
            break;
        case 'C':
            // do stuff
            break;
    }
```

Note: I think you may have a problem in your code in that it seems to me you should be switching on the `initpolicyNo`, not the actual types?